# How to limit the number of characters in @Html.TextArea?

Tags: html, html-helper

Having this line of code:

```
@Html.TextArea("userInput")
```

How to limit the number of characters in the **userInput** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

@Html.TextArea("userInput",new { maxlength=50 })

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

textarea has a "maxlength" attribute, which does exactly what you are looking for. If this text is going into a server somewhere or some client-side JavaScript, I would recommend verifying the length in that code as well. However. the max length attribute is sufficient for just display.